# Can the number of units in NN input layer be different than the number of features in the data?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Based on the tensorflow keras API tutorial;

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', input_shape=(32,)),
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

I couldn't understand that why the number of units in the input layer is 10 while the input shape is 32. Also, there are many examples like this one in the tensorflow tutorials.

Comment: That means that the inputs are vectors of 32 numbers, and the output of the first layer is a vector of 10 numbers. That is, it has something like a 32x10 matrix of parameters (plus 10-vector of biases). The sizes of each layer on a neural network is pretty much arbitrary and do not need to depend on the size of the input.

Comment: So how many units are there in the input layer in this case? @jdehesa

Comment: The input layer in this case would have 32 units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather common confusion by new practitioners, and not without a reason: the answer, as it has already been hinted at in the comments, is that in the Keras Sequential API there is an *implicit* input layer, determined by the `input_shape` argument of the first explicit layer.

This is directly visible in the Keras Functional API (check the [example](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#first-example-a-densely-connected-network) in the docs), where `Input` is an explicit layer itself, and in which your model would be written as:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(32,))                     # input layer
x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(inputs)     # hidden layer
outputs = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)    # output layer

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

i.e. your model is actually an example of a "good old" neural net with three layers (input, hidden, and output), despite that it looks like a two-layer net in the Keras Sequential API.

(BTW, and irrelevant to the question, it does not make much sense to have `softmax` as activation for your hidden layer.)